In Zsh using Node.js it splits the array to a new line when over a certain length - Would like to keep it on the same line
When I console.log() an array it splits it over a certain length. I would like to keep it on one line as my terminal is large enough.
I could use join() but I am hoping for a permanent solution maybe something I can update in the .zshrc. Not sure if it is node.js or zsh causing the new line. What steps do I need to take to correct this.
What it is doing now:
Test Case 1: [ 1, 9, 49, 81, 484, 900 ]
Test Case 2: [
  0, 1,  1,  4,
  9, 9, 16, 25
]
Test Case 3: [ 1, 4, 9, 25 ]
Test Case 4: [ 0, 4, 4, 16, 16 ]

What I want it to do:
Test Case 1: [ 1, 9, 49, 81, 484, 900 ]
Test Case 2: [ 0, 1,  1,  4, 9, 9, 16, 25 ]
Test Case 3: [ 1, 4, 9, 25 ]
Test Case 4: [ 0, 4, 4, 16, 16 ]

The code that is used to print the statement is as follows.
const printArray = [
  [ 1, 9, 49, 81, 484, 900 ],
  [ 0, 1,  1,  4, 9, 9, 16, 25 ],
  [ 1, 4, 9, 25 ],
  [ 0, 4, 4, 16, 16 ],
];

printArray.forEach((array, index) => {
  console.log(`Test Case ${index + 1}:`, array);
});

(This might be a tangent) Testing without array in the variable
console.log('Test Console 1: [ 1, 9, 49, 81, 484, 900 ]');
console.log('Test Console 2: [ 0, 1,  1,  4, 9, 9, 16, 25 ]');
console.log('Test Console 3: [ 1, 4, 9, 25 ]');
console.log('Test Console 4: [ 0, 4, 4, 16, 16 ]');

// Result
Test Console 1: [ 1, 9, 49, 81, 484, 900 ]
Test Console 2: [ 0, 1,  1,  4, 9, 9, 16, 25 ]
Test Console 3: [ 1, 4, 9, 25 ]
Test Console 4: [ 0, 4, 4, 16, 16 ]

Interestingly enough the console.log() does not split the array but anytime the array is in a variable, it splits the array.
// Array stored in a variable
singleArray =  [ 0, 1,  1,  4, 9, 9, 16, 25 ]
console.log('single array:', singleArray);

single array: [
  0, 1,  1,  4,
  9, 9, 16, 25
]


How does the statement which prints the array look like? What is (in zsh) the value of the shell variable COLUMNS?

I check echo $COLUMNS which came out to 80. I increased it to 200 by export COLUMNS=200. I still had the same result as above.

I just wanted to make sure, that zsh is not the culprit. Hence I would conclude that console.log is doing this (on its own). I believe that you can at least erase the zsh tag. Try to reduce the number of elements in singleArray one by one, to see at which point no reformatting is done. The tests "without a variable" are not informative, because you don't pass in them array, just a string. I could imagine that log never splits a string, but splits the elements of an array.  The "not in a variable" test case would be console.log('Test Console 2:', [ 0, 1,  1,  4, 9, 9, 16, 25 ]);.

Thank you for helping me get down to the bottom of this issue. Thank you for correcting the test case. You make a very good point about the console.log() being the culprit. I am using Node.js and it seems there is no way to change the default array length which is in place for debugging purposes in util.inspect file. Related issue
